# Javascript-Selenium WebDriverJS (Not Java using ashot)- Full page screenshot

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, allure

In selenium WebdriverJS, how to take a full page screenshot?

Browser: Chrome

For current window screenshot:

```
var screenshot = await driver.takeScreenshot();
```

Ashot not available in node.js?

Need it for selenium webdriver-javascript not using java.